# C# application which requires access key to activate licence

Tags: c#, licensing

I believe all of you had used some Microsoft product in the past and you are all well familiar with typing in long access key in order to activate your licence.

I want my C# application to have  the exact same feature, all I would like to know is how can this be done ?

Comment: You may want to clarify your q with aspects about your business model. Are we talking about paid licenses? If you just want to make sure that your users pay for using the application then a store app may be enough. Microsoft will take 30% but you don't have to deal with licensing or with payment processing (that gets even more complicated). If you want to charge a monthly / annual license fee then you may be able to do that with an app store in-app  purchases although I am not sure. If you insist to handle all that on your own then you will have to write server side code + DB.

Comment: I did considered using an app store, unfortunately I'm trying to target businesses. Most businesses use windows 7 or xp and internet explorer browser, I don't think Microsoft included any form of app stores back when these were used